# Moving rotated arrow in straight line

Tags: math, graphics, rotation, webgl

I'm trying to move an arrow, which could be rotated, in a straight line. I'm having some difficulty coming up with the correct formula to use. I know it should probably involve sine and cosine, but I've tried various configurations and haven't been able to get something that works.

Here's a picture of my scene with the arrow and bow
[image: Here's a picture of my scene with the arrow and bow.]

rotateNumber is an integer like -1 (for 1 left rotation), 0 (no rotation), 1 (1 right rotation), etc.

rotateAngle is 10 degrees by default.

Here's the code to move the arrow:

```
    if (arrowMoving) {
      var rAngle = rotateAngle * rotateNumber;
      var angleInRad = rAngle * (Math.PI/180);
      var stepSize = 1/20;
      arrowX += stepSize * Math.cos(angleInRad);
      arrowY += stepSize * Math.sin(angleInRad);
      DrawArrowTranslate(arrowX, arrowY);
      requestAnimFrame(render);
    } else {
      DrawArrow();
      arrowX = 0;
      arrowY = 0;
    }
```

Here's the code to draw and translate the arrow:

```
function DrawArrowTranslate(tx, ty) {
    modelViewStack.push(modelViewMatrix);

  /*
  var s = scale4(0.3, -0.7, 1);
    var t = translate(0, -4, 0);
  */
  var s = scale4(0.3, -0.7, 1);
    var t = translate(0, -5, 0);
  var t2 = translate(0 + tx, 1 + ty, 0)

    // rotate takes angle in degrees
    var rAngle = rotateAngle;

    var r = rotate(rAngle, 0, 0, 1);

    var m = mult(t, r);
  var m = mult(m, t2);
  modelViewMatrix = mat4();
    modelViewMatrix = mult(modelViewMatrix, m);
    modelViewMatrix = mult(modelViewMatrix, s);

  /*
  // update bounding box
  arrowBoundingBox.translate(0, -5);
  arrowBoundingBox.rotate(rAngle);
  arrowBoundingBox.translate(0, 1);
  arrowBoundingBox.scale(0.3, -0.7);
  */

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixLoc, false, flatten(modelViewMatrix));
  gl.drawArrays( gl.LINE_STRIP, 1833, 4);
  gl.drawArrays( gl.LINE_STRIP, 1837, 4);

    modelViewMatrix = modelViewStack.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks quite correct, but you should eliminate the use of the rotateNumber. You can just use positive and negative angles for rotation instead, eliminating what I imagine is the cause of error here.
Sin and Cos can certainly handle angles of any magnitude positive, negative, or zero.
Good luck!

Comment: Note: Consider the unit circle and how positive angles are counterclockwise, starting from pointing directly to the rift.

Comment: I've changed it to eliminate rotateNumber and it still doesn't work. It works if pointing completely to the left, otherwise it moves in the wrong direction. For example, with no rotation it moves directly to the right instead of straight up.

Comment: In your coordinate system is (0,0) in the top left corner

Comment: No it's webgl with some orthographic projection where (0, 0) is in the center of the screen.

Comment: Mathematically an angle of zero points directly to the right so if you want that to be straight up add 90 degrees or pi/2 radians. Then, the angles will go in the counterclockwise direction. So 10 degrees would be pointing up and to the left

Comment: Webgl’s rotation scheme might not match the mathematical rotation if that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah I had just started playing around with that idea. However, I'm still having some issues with that: it goes straight up with no rotation, but it doesn't work for any other angles. For example, when I point the bow and arrow directly to the left or right it goes straight down instead of either left or right. Similarly for the other possible angles.

Comment: For rotation I'm using transformation matrices such as described here: https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/goa/mallinnus/3dtransf/3drot.html the rotations are also using sine and cosine and appear to match math as its simply using the mathematical matrices.

Comment: Are you rotating the arrow that way and then also moving it using the rotation, causing it to actually move with double the expected rotation?

Comment: Because if that is the case, you might be able to just move the arrow by a y step of 1/20 and that would just work, if the rotation is being applied using the transformation matrix

Comment: There does seem to be a bug in how the translate and rotate is happening. I'm looking through it now, I posted the code also.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I was translating after rotating when I needed to translate before rotating as the rotation was messing up the translation.

Comment: Great! I was wondering if it was some issue with the translation being screwed up by something along the way with Webgl. I’m glad you got it working

Comment: Applying translation after or before rotation are two valide ways to acheive transformation. But in the first case (translate after rotation : T*R), it performs what we call a translation in local space, so to say : along matrix axes, axes that were modified by the rotation. This is sometime very usefull.